# How to use notifications menu in @ant-design/pro-layout?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I have designed my project with CRA and antd, unfortunately AFAIK antd layout don't have a notifications, user options in the header.

So I tried to use @ant-design/pro-layout, it's bit confusing in the documentation on how to use the notifications and user options in menu.

[image: User notifications in and design pro]

Anyone please shed some light on how to achieve this with either in antd or in @ant-design/pro-layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think docs in v4 are still under development but you can downgrade the documentation to v2 and see how they do it (or dig their github repo) what i can find is:

you have to:

```
import NoticeIcon from 'ant-design-pro/lib/NoticeIcon'
```

see reference here:

https://v2-pro.ant.design/components/notice-icon

and more information here :

https://v2-pro.ant.design/docs/use-components-alone